# MS Calculator on windows 7. I need to know how it does its operations

Tags: c++, math, decimal, octal

MS calculator on windows 7 has a "programmers" mode. When I type in  (in binary): 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

and then click "Dec", the binary turns into -1. When I click Oct, the value turns into 
1777777777777777777777

However, whenever I use an online converter, it doesn't work. I need to know how the calculator is doing this so I can emulate it in c++.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, just as everywhere else in life, "it doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of a problem. Always describe what you expected to happen as well as what actually happened instead.

Answer (score 7):

It is using 64 bit two's complement notation.  Basically, when you add one to `2^63 - 1`, it overflows and you get `-2^63`.  [Wikipedia for more detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_complement)

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of 2s complement? It all depends (logically on the length of the binary number. Hardware lets you work with one word at a time, however.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) when you switch it to decimal. In octal form, it is doing a straight conversion.